# Concurrent Moving Average Window in Java using a Queue?

Tags: java, multithreading

Hi I'm creating a Moving Average Window (MAW) data structure in Java using a ConcurrentLinkedQueue. The MAW can be called by multiple threads at the same time so I need to make sure my code is thread safe - the only way I can see to do this is have a synchronized code block (using the Queue as the lock) in the add method:

```
final Queue<Double> myQ = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Double>();
volatile double total;
volatile int count;
```

In the add method I have:

```
synchronized (myQ)
{
   if (myQ.offer(value))
   {
      total += value;
      count++;
   }
   if (size > window)
   {
      total -= myQ.poll();
      count--;
   }
   movingAvg = total / count;
}
```

I do not see anyway round not having the synchronized code block?

Thanks

Comment: What's your actual question here? Are you asking if there is a way to do this without any locking mechanism?

Comment: Yes - my question is there away to do it without the synchronized code block and still maintain thread safety? thanks

Comment: The answer to any question that is "do I need to synchronize x...?" is the same as the answer to "do I have a mutable object that is undergoing a state transition that takes more than 1 discrete step?"  Otherwise threads can cause race conditions and/or view the object at a point where it is an invalid, transitional, and/or inconsistent state.  Exceptions exist where mutable objects offer their own internal synchronization.  Your state transition appears to require more than one step, so ....

Comment: why do you need synchronized collection and volatile variables if you do all computation under the lock? It looks like double synchronization.

Comment: volatile is used so the variable will never be cached thread-locally and always read from main memory.

Comment: @val: His object has the queue, but also other instance variables that comprise its state.  Access to the Queue may be synchronized, but one must consider what is the atomicity of the state transition for the whole object.  You want the state transition to either fully occur or not occur at all ... otherwise other threads can view or access the object in an invalid state.

Comment: Thanks, so yes as I need it all done in one atomic operation I need to lock the code. Was just curious if there is a better way (performance wise) to do it using the java.util.concurrent package? Haven't coded in Java for awhile so don't have any experience with that package.

Comment: @Pat: I don't believe that locking on the queue, myQ, is adequate to guarantee the atomicity of state transitions to your object which contains other instance fields in addition to myQ.  You probably want to use a different monitor object in this case, eg. `this`.

Comment: @scottb Do you explain why we need ConcurrentLinkedQueue instead of simple Queue?

Comment: @Val: we'd need to see the rest of the code for his app.  If all the access to the queue was guarded by an appropriate external lock anyway, then it may not be necessary to use ConcurrentLinkedQueue.

Comment: Yes, as the queue is only accessed through this MAW class - any Queue impl would work I guess

Comment: @scottb Yes. But, do you see that thread-safe volatiles use a different lock and, thus, can vary their values despite while you keep the shown lock. That is why I think other lock makes no sense and, thus, using synchronized integers and collection just wastes resources and performance. Using volatile to avoid caching is utterest nonsense.

Comment: @Pat, are you going to use parallelism to degrade the performance?

Comment: @Pat What Val is saying is that `volatile` is needed in the absence of `synchronized`.  Synchronized has the same memory effects as volatile.  So if the variables listed are only accessed within the sync block you  do not need volatile.  The same holds true for a concurrent queue.

Comment: @Val, no other the that multiple threads can call the MW class at the same time.

Comment: @John, ok I had thought volatile just meant the variable was always read from main memory and not the cache. So when the variable is always only accessed from within a synchronized code block there is no need to declare it as volatile at all. Thanks

Comment: @Pat Yes exactly.  This is because the next thread can only read the variable upon acquiring the synchronized lock, which obviously isn't dont until after the writing thread releases that lock.  This creates a happens-before relationship.  But all reads and writes need to be done under the *same* lock in order to satisfy this relationship

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of a way unless you are OK with getting slightly wrong values.

On the other hand, one of the most performance conscious implementation uses a lock, too ([the metrics library](https://github.com/codahale/metrics/blob/master/metrics-core/src/main/java/com/codahale/metrics/SlidingWindowReservoir.java)).

Lock acquisition got very fast since JDK6. If I were you I'd just use a lock.

Comment: That's an interesting implementation using just synchronization on an array, much simpler than messing with queues.